# SQL Checking if Date is within this or prior calendar year

Tags: sql

How do you check if a date is within this or the prior calendar year.

I.E. December 31, This Year > myDate > January 1, Last Year

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? sql server, mysql, oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard SQL way is to use EXTRACT:

```
select *
from t
where extract(year from t.thedate) = extract(year from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) or
      extract(year from t.thedate) = extract(year from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1
```

Not all databases support these functions; but all do have a way of extracting the date somehow.  For instance, many support the `year` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE TO_DATE("FROM-DATE") < DateColumn AND TO_DATE("END-DATE") > DateColumn
```

This is in Oracle, pretty sure MySQL SQLite or other databases have this function,

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you could use `DATEDIFF`:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(year,myDate,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) in (0,1)
```

`DATEDIFF(year,...` effectively computes the number of year transitions between the dates (or to put it another way, the number of new year's eves at midnight).

For larger tables where indexes may help your query, we'd need to instead transform `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and compare `myDate` against those computed values:

```
WHERE myDate >= DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'20000101') AND
      myDate < DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'20020101')
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you could do this:

```
DECLARE @yourDate DATETIME;
SELECT @yourDate = '2012-06-02';

SELECT CASE YEAR(@yourDate)
          WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'Same Year'
          WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 THEN 'Last Year'
          ELSE 'Other Year'
       END AS YourColumn;
```

You can also easily expand this if you had to look for future dates, or more than one year in the past.

Other RDBMS will offer similar functionality to check the year for your dates.